# Looking for a proof of this statement

Tags: multivariate-analysis, proof

Let the data matrix $\pmb X$ be a collection of $n$ $p$-vectors $x_i\sim\mathcal{E}_p(\mu,\pmb \varSigma)$ where $\mathcal{E}_p(\mu,\pmb \varSigma)$ is a square integrable, continuous elliptical density on $\mathbb{R}^p$ with location vector $\mu$ and scatter matrix $\pmb\varSigma$ and $n>p$. Then let $\{S_m\}_{m=1}^M$ be $p$ indexes drawn from $\{1:n\}$ with $M=\binom{n}{p}$. Then let $A_m=\{x_i|i\in S_m\}$ and $y_m\in\mathbb{R}^p:\pmb A_m'y_m=1_p$ ($1_p$ denotes a $p$-vector of ones).

$$\underset{1\le m\le M}{\max}\;\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max}\;(x_i'y_m-1)^2||y_m||^{-2}\text{ is bounded}$$

I'm looking for a reference to a proof (presumably of a more general variant) of (or a counter-example to) this statement.

## EDIT1:

a '$p$ index' is a subset of $p$ elements of $\{1:n\}$ drawn randomly and without replacement. There are $\binom{n}{p}$ distinct such $p$-subsets of $\{1:n\}$. $m\in\{1,\ldots,M\}$.  $x_i$ is indeed a row of $\pmb X$. $\pmb A_m$ is a $p$ by $p$ matrix formed of $p$ rows of $\pmb X$ with indexes in $S_m$.

## EDIT2:

following Mike McCoy's question. For a given $y_m$ the inner product $x_i'y_m=1$ only for the $x_i$ with index $i\in S_m$. Here is a short R code to illustrate.

```
n<-20
p<-3
X<-matrix(rnorm(n*p),nc=p)
S_m<-sample(1:n,p)
A_m<-X[S_m,]
y_m<-solve(A_m,rep(1,p)) #equation of the hyperplane through the members of S_m
dis<-tcrossprod(X%*%y_m-1)/as.numeric(crossprod(y_m))
```

stated otherwise, the claim is that the $\max$ (over all possible $M$ subsets $S_m$) of the sup norm of `dis` is bounded whenever $\pmb X$ is drawn from a square integrable and continuous density.

## EDIT3:

to address Mike McCoy's questions. By bounded, I mean that

$$\exists U(\mu, \pmb \varSigma):\underset{1\le m\le M}{\max}\;\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max}\;(x_i'y_m-1)^2||y_m||^{-2}\le U(\mu, \pmb \varSigma)\;a.s.$$

for some positive scalar $U(\mu, \pmb \varSigma)$ depending only on $\pmb \varSigma$ and $\mu$. Again, I suspect this theorem (or even a more general version of it) has been proven. I just can't locate the reference.

Comment: It is unclear what $\{S_m\}$ is: what exactly is a "$p$ index"?  How are they "drawn"? In the subsequent statements it looks like this set is merely $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, because its elements are used to index "$x$" (which presumably is the same as $X$, with "$x_i$" denoting a row of $X$, right?). What is $m$? When you are this abstract, you have to be *absolutely precise and accurate* in your notation.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some context to help us understand the question, and its relation to statistics, a bit better. This would probably generate more interest in this seemingly obscure question. A more descriptive title would also be nice.

Comment: @whuber I have edited the question to answer your questions. Let me know if it still doesn't addresses them satisfactorily. Mike McCoy: it's really a lemma that I need for a proof. I'm not sure if it can be, in itself, framed in an obvious practical application. I presume a more general version of this statement has been shown before/elsewhere.

Comment: I must not understand the question: By definition of $y_m$, the inner product $x_i'y_m=1$, right? Since $y_m\ne 0$, the maximum is always zero...

Comment: @MikeMcCoy: thanks for your question. I will edit my question to make this point more clear. Please let me know if the question remains unclear.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "is bounded"? Has a finite expectation? Almost surely? What can the bound depend on? ($X$? the distribution of $X$?)  The difficulty of the question depends strongly on the type of bound you are looking for.

Comment: @MikeMcCoy: thanks again for suggestions. I will append the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement, as of edit 3, is **False**. Suppose, say, that $X$ are iid multivariate standard normal $N(0,I)$ random variables.  Pick $i$ such that $i \notin S_m$. Then the vector $x_i$ is independents of $A_m$, and hence independent of $y_m$. Then for any constant $C$, we have

$$ \mathbb{P} \{ (x_i' y_m - 1)^2 \ge C\|y_m\|^2 \} = \mathbb{E}_{y_m}\left[\mathbb{P}_{x_i}\bigl\{(x_i'y_m-1)^2\ge C \|y_m\|^2\bigr\}\right] > 0$$

since the inner probability on the right is always positive. (This holds because the Gaussian distribution is supported over all space, and hence for each fixed $y_m$, the values $x_i'y_m$ grow arbitrarily large with nonzero probability.)

Comment: Thanks! One question however: you seem to be assuming $n\rightarrow\infty$, but my question is for fixed $n$.

Comment: There is no $n\to \infty$. For each fixed $n$, the random variable $(x'_i y_m-1)^2/\|y_m\|^2$ has unbounded support when $i\notin S_m$.  This answers your question to the negative.